# Is it possible to return 10 SOLR docs that match one condition and 10 docs that match another condition for a total of count=20 docs in same query?

Tags: solr, union

I need to return a total of 20 documents from a SOLR collection. I need 10 documents that match one field value and 10 that match a different value for the same field. Can this be done in a single SOLR query?

Example (multiple lines for readability):

```
http://myhost/mycollection?
fq=is_deleted:false AND vehicle_type:(car OR truck)
&q=vehicle_name:(*blue* *driver*)
&fl=vehicle_name,vehicle_type
&count=20
&start=0
&sort=score desc
```

The problem is I might get 20 cars and 0 trucks, depending on which docs rank higher and how many docs there are of each type. What I need is a max of 10 cars and 10 trucks.

In SQL, you could accomplish this in a single query by writing two separate queries (one for 10 trucks and one for 10 cars), then combine the results with a UNION statement.

Is there any way to accomplish this in SOLR?

What I have tried is the above query, but I often get 20 docs of one type and none of the other type.

I am also looking into SOLR facets and SOLR grouping to see if I might be able to use one of them to accomplish this.

Related questions (with no satisfactory answer):

- [Usage of UNION and MINUS in SOLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539461/usage-of-union-and-minus-in-solr)
- [How to combine results from multiple solr queries (much like UNION on SQL's)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474418/how-to-combine-results-from-multiple-solr-queries-much-like-union-on-sqls)
- [Any way to merge two queries in solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664847/any-way-to-merge-two-queries-in-solr)
- [SOLR Union of two queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911795/solr-union-of-two-queries)

Related question (with similar answer)

- [solr - execute multiple queries in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388005/solr-execute-multiple-queries-in-one-request)

**Solution**

(based on MatsLindh's suggestions below)
I used group.field instead of group.query and I added group.main which instructs solr to return a flat list of results.

```
http://myhost/mycollection?
fq=is_deleted:false AND vehicle_type:(car OR truck)
&q=vehicle_name:(*blue* *driver*)
&fl=vehicle_name,vehicle_type
&count=20
&start=0
&sort=score desc
&group=true
&group.field=vehicle_type
&group.limit=10
&group.main=true
&group.sort=score desc
```

**References**

- https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/result-grouping.html
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/FieldCollapsing#Quick_Start

Comment: `group=true&group.query=vehicle_type:car&group.query=vehicle_type:truck&group.limit=10` might do what you want, `group.format=simple` might also be useful, but I'm not sure if `group.limit` is still respected per group - test it. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response @MatsLindh, I'm experimenting with the grouping options now!

Comment: @MatsLindh Using the example you provided, I have been able to get this to work properly. Can you add it as a answer to the question and I will accept it as the best answer?